# error: "struct" expression not at top level

Tags: macros, julia, syntax-error, metaprogramming

```
function check(str,arg;type=DataType,max=nothing,min=nothing,description="")
    @argcheck typeof(arg)==type
    @argcheck arg>min
    @argcheck arg<max
    @argcheck typeof(description)==String
   return arg
end


 function constr(name,arg,field)
        return :(function $name($arg,$field)
            new(check($name,$arg,$field))
        end)
    end
    
macro creatStruct(name,arg)
   code = Base.remove_linenums!(quote
     struct $name
        end
     end)
     print(arg)
   append!(code.args[1].args[3].args,[constr(name,arg.args[1].args[1],arg.args[1].args[2])])
   code 
end 

macro myStruct(name,arg)
    @creatStruct name arg
  end 





@myStruct test12 (
  (arg1,(max=10))
)
```

In my code above I'm trying to build a `macro` that Creates a `struct`, and within the struct, you can define an argument with boundaries (max, min) and description, etc.
I'm getting this error:
syntax: `"#141#max = 10" is not a valid function argument name`

and every time I'm trying to solve it, I get another error like:
`LoadError: syntax: "struct" expression not at top level`

So, I think my Code/Approach is not that cohesive. Anybody can suggest tips and/or another Approche.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. You're attempting to make an argument name `max` with a default value of `10`. The error is about `max=10` not being a valid name (`Symbol`), while `max` is. The bigger issue is you're trying to put this in the `struct` expression instead of a constructor *method*:

```
struct Foo
  bar::Float64
  max::Int64
end

# constructor
Foo(bar, max=10) = Foo(bar, max)
```

So you have to figure out how to make an expression for a method with default values, too.

2. Your second error means that `struct`s must be defined in the top-level. "Top-level" is like global scope but stricter in some contexts; I don't know the exact difference, but it definitely excludes local scopes (`macro`, `function`, etc). It looks like the issue is the expression returned by `creatStruct` being evaluated as code in `myStruct`, but the `LoadError` I'm getting has a different message. In any case, the error goes away if I make sure things stay as expressions:

```
macro myStruct(name,arg)
    :(@creatStruct $name $arg)
end
```